# NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative how does it work?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, finite-difference-method

I'm referring to [Paritosh Mokhasi's blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/07/09/using-mathematica-to-simulate-and-visualize-fluid-flow-in-a-box/), where he uses, along with some other things, the...let's call it a function (?)... NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative. I was able to use it exactly the same way as he does in Mathematica 11 (works on both even and uneven grid):

```
ugrid = Range[0, 8];
Thread[{Thread[
   Map[f'[#] &, ugrid] == 
    NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], ugrid, 
     Map[f, ugrid]]]}]

{{Derivative[1][f][0] == -((25 f[0])/12) + 4 f[1] - 3 f[2] + (4 f[3])/
    3 - f[4]/4}, {Derivative[1][f][1] == -(f[0]/4) - (5 f[1])/6 + (
    3 f[2])/2 - f[3]/2 + f[4]/12}, {Derivative[1][f][2] == 
   f[0]/12 - (2 f[1])/3 + (2 f[3])/3 - f[4]/12}, {Derivative[1][f][
    3] == f[1]/12 - (2 f[2])/3 + (2 f[4])/3 - f[5]/12}, {Derivative[
    1][f][4] == 
   f[2]/12 - (2 f[3])/3 + (2 f[5])/3 - f[6]/12}, {Derivative[1][f][
    5] == f[3]/12 - (2 f[4])/3 + (2 f[6])/3 - f[7]/12}, {Derivative[
    1][f][6] == 
   f[4]/12 - (2 f[5])/3 + (2 f[7])/3 - f[8]/12}, {Derivative[1][f][
    7] == -(f[4]/12) + f[5]/2 - (3 f[6])/2 + (5 f[7])/6 + f[8]/
    4}, {Derivative[1][f][8] == 
   f[4]/4 - (4 f[5])/3 + 3 f[6] - 4 f[7] + (25 f[8])/12}}
```

I've been thinking that this could be used also on 2D grid...so our ugrid would be something two-dimensional (just a simple square even grid)

```
grid = Partition[Flatten@Table[{x,y}, {x,0,5,0.2}, {y,0,5,0.2}], 2];
```

Now the symbolic `Derivative[1]` should be changed to `Derivative[1,0]` as to account for the partial derivative in the `x`-direction. Also, Map[f, grid] does not work for me, but `f@@@grid` does (don't you get a rollmop craving while reading this?) :

```
f@@@grid
{f[0., 0.], f[0., 0.2], f[0., 0.4], f[0., 0.6], f[0., 0.8], f[0., 1.],
  f[0., 1.2], f[0., 1.4], f[0., 1.6], f[0., 1.8],...}
```

Now, analogically to the previous, I invoke

```
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1, 0], grid, f @@@ grid]
```

just to get the error

```
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative::ldim: {{0.,0.},{0.,0.2},{0.,0.4},{0.,0.6},{0.,0.8},{0.,1.},{0.,1.2},{0.,1.4},{0.,1.6},{0.,1.8},{0.,2.},<<30>>,{0.2,3.},{0.2,3.2},{0.2,3.4},{0.2,3.6},{0.2,3.8},{0.2,4.},{0.2,4.2},{0.2,4.4},{0.2,4.6},<<626>>} should be a list with an element for each of the 2 dimensions.
```

The funny thing is: this *is* a list of pairs. What is wrong?

The problem is, that I can't find this NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative in documentation at all (besides just a bunch of messages/errors). Is it deprecated? What is modern version of this function? How would you rewrite the   Paritosh Mokhasi's code for two dimensions? How to write that two-dimensional analogue of derivative (in case of an uneven grid, or a mixed second-order derivative which both requires mixing of variables)? Neither of these work:

```
Map[D[f[#1,#2],#1] &, grid]
Map[Derivative[1, 0] f[#1, #2] &, grid]
```

The last try looks promising:

```
(Derivative[1, 0] f[#1, #2] &) @@@ grid
```

as the output is:

```
{Derivative[1, 0] f[0., 0.], Derivative[1, 0] f[0., 0.2], 
 Derivative[1, 0] f[0., 0.4], Derivative[1, 0] f[0., 0.6], ...}
```

(is it what I wanted?)

Thank you.

Comment: Select the first link in the help browser for `FiniteDifferenceDerivative`.

Comment: Paritosh's code does work for 2D.

Comment: Oh, that one well-hidden documentation! Although it seems it only works for grids that can be written as a tensor product of 1D lists...IE, it won't work for grids generated by the `ToElementMesh[]` function...

Comment: Well, finite difference methods really are not intended for the result of `ToElementMesh[]`; it is a FEM function after all.

Comment: But is there any analogue which can be used in case of the `ToElementMesh[]`?

Comment: That's a different question, possibly for another thread.

Comment: Yes, look for the FEM programming tutorial and the functions there in. Type "FEM" in the help browser. See the See Also section in `ToElementMesh` and the Related Guides.

Comment: Okay thanks, this questions is more about documentation...